# Point of extra space when using strpos

Tags: php, parsing

I have seen this in several functions that use strpos, but can't wrap my head around the purpose of adding an extra space. Can someone please help me understand this.

Example is the function get_string_between (see below) which returns whatever is between 2 tags. So for the string "**this is my [tag]dog[/tag]**" it will return-> **dog**

I understand what the function does, but what is the purpose of

```
$string = ' ' . $string;
```

Inside the following:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = 'this is my [tag]dog[/tag]';
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '[tag]', '[/tag]');

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)
```

Comment: no purpose, you can remove that line and execute. still the same output.

Comment: As Far As I Tested, If I remove that space, everything works fine, That space doesn't serve any purpose...

Comment: It's a hack to prevent an error from occurring if the [tag] doesn't exist in the string.

Comment: @Anant Not true. The `if` expression would have to be `$ini === false` instead of `$ini == 0` for that be true.

Comment: I have tested  it by removing that line and no effect happen.

Comment: Looks like they added it so they don't have to deal with when `strpos` returns false. It is a little odd way of doing it, but the result is the same.

Comment: You may ask here to get exact ans : http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/03/31/php-parse-a-string-between-two-strings/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they added it so they don't have to deal with when `strpos` returns `false`. It is a little odd way of doing it, but the result is the same.

Here is a more robust example:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {

    // String is empty, will never find anything
    if (strlen($string) === 0) {
        return '';
    }
    // Empty tags, not possible to find in the string
    if (strlen($start) === 0 || strlen($end) === 0) {
        return '';
    }
    $startIndex = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($startIndex === false) {
        return ''; // Start not found in string
    }
    // Get end with offset of start, so it must appear
    // after the start tag
    $endIndex = strpos($string, $end, $startIndex);
    if ($endIndex === false) {
        return ''; // End not found in string
    }
    $from = ($startIndex + strlen($start));
    $length = ($endIndex - $from);

    return substr($string, $from, $length);
}
```

Or you can use a regular expression:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
    if (strlen($string) === 0 || strlen($start) === 0 || strlen($end) === 0) {
        return '';
    }
    $start = preg_quote($start, '/');
    $end = preg_quote($end, '/');
    preg_match("/(?<=$start).*?(?=$end)/", $string, $result);
    if (count($result) > 0) {
        return array_shift($result);
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: regex solution looks very elegant! would it still work if the $start contains special characters like /?. etc. Can it be combined with something like real_escape_string to make it even more foolproof?

Comment: @RobertSinclair `preg_quote` takes care of special characters.